# workflow parameter in glue job

Tags: python, aws-glue

I am trying to get the parameter send from workflow to glue job

When I print sys.argv I saw below output

```
['/tmp/test.py', 'true', '--job-bookmark-option', 'job-bookmark-disable', '--JOB_ID', 'j_a2c2431d004536b0074916df19f8e811b95eb2488d807fbfbdd3f32f302b5f35', 'true', '--JOB_RUN_ID', 'jr_a8e08e57ccce2bf21b3ef2c3e8f6fed8c6f01e08391319049d566aa753b59dfb', '--WORKFLOW_NAME', 'test-wf', 'client', 'value12', '--JOB_NAME', 'test-job', '--WORKFLOW_RUN_ID', 'wr_49ad1e976fc67f56db8436613726864411746d58588ad80312eb710a3e950ec1', '--TempDir', 's3://aws-glue-assets-565472381763-us-west-2/temporary/']
```

so  **client** key is there, but when I am trying to access in job, it's saying client is required.

The code I tried

```
    args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['client'])
```

What I am doing wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `--client` in your arguments.

Like this:

```py
['...', '--client', 'value12', '...']
```

and then

```py
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['client'])
```